# Calling a Ruby(Not Rails) variable using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax

I have some experience in both Ruby and JavaScript, but I've never had to integrate the two. I have searched this site, and found that any possible answers refer to Rails, which I am not using.

My problem is this: I need to pull a variable from another file, and use it's data to populate an empty `DIV`. I researched, and found that since JS is client code and Ruby is server, you cannot communicate with both at the same time directly. The solution was AJAX, but I have used AJAX all of once before, to do some very simple calling. 
Here's my code:

Javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

  $(function()
  {
      $.ajax({
          url: "Main.rb"
          data: '{"method" : "get_Sched_name", "variable" : "@schedules"}'
      });
  });
```

Ruby:

```
def get_Sched_name
  @schedules = repository.adapter.select "SELECT name FROM schedules"
end
```

Comment: What is `repository`?

Comment: A URL of "main.rb" doesn't make any sense. You need to hooking your ruby code up to a web server (could be rails, Sinatra, old style cgi etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can evaluate `@schedules` using ERB, i.e.

```
data: '{"method" : "get_Sched_name", "variable" : "<%= @schedules %>"}'
```